# Even if I set my screen size condition, navbar is affected with the function I created for changing the logo size when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a function for my navbar brand to change size when scrolling down and goes back to the original size and position when scrolling up. There are no problems with changes in large size screen (bootstrap grid). But my navbar is still affected by the function even if I set the (screen.width > 992). I'm not able to figure out the cause. Kindly help.

Here's my code:

CSS

```
.scroll-navbrand {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

JS

```
function navChange() {
  $(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('.navbar-brand').addClass('scroll-navbrand');
    } else {
      $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('scroll-navbrand');
    }
  });
}

if (screen.width > 992) {
  navChange();
}
```

Comment: so `navChange` is called when the screen width is greater than 992 ... so it seems you want the navbar affected even if the screen.width > 992 ... did you mean to affect the navbar if screen.width < 992 ?

Comment: Try `$(window).on("resize", function() {  });`

Comment: Everything is fine when the screen is greater than 992. My main problem is that screensize below 992 is affected by the navChange. When I try to scroll down below 992, navbar has a margin bottom when scrolling down. And if I scroll it back, it will just stay with a margin at the bottom.

Comment: Issue is already resolved after I include the css style in media query for < 992. Appreciate your help!